# What does the three different volume specifications mean for the Gregory Whitney backpack?

Tags: backpacking, backpacks

REI's web page for the [Gregory Whitney backpack](https://www.rei.com/product/766117/gregory-whitney-95-pack) lists its volume as

> 87 / 95 / 103 liter

What do you think this exactly mean? Does the backpack have three different ways to use with these different volumes? If so, any idea how they are different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The increase in pack height to accommodate the S, M and L torso ranges changes the capacity. You'll note the weight is also different because of the extra fabric needed. The hipbelts usually change size quite a bit also since you apparently can't have a tall torso with a skinny waist.

Comment: I easily break the torso waist rule. It's not actually a good thing. it's really hard to find a pack that sits on my back and holds around my waist nicely.

Comment: @Desorder I don't know if it's a good rule in the first place, I'm only 5'9" and I can barely find packs that are small enough for my waist

Comment: @Raystafarian That's what I said. :D

Answer (score 6):

It looks like those the backpack comes in three sizes, **Small**, **Medium** and **Large** and what you are seeing is the volume for each size.